# Прогрессбар tqdm, отображение шагов при изменяемом шаге иттерации

Tags: python

Например при обработке N файлов разной длины, хочется видеть и пофайловый прогрес (М из N) и суммарный прогресс времени, с учетом их размера.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

fmt = '{percentage:3.0f}% ({n_fmt} of {total_fmt})'
iteration = (3, 2, 1, 4)
bar = tqdm(total=sum(iteration), bar_format=fmt)
for i in iteration:
    sleep(i)
    bar.update(i)
```

Будет отображать:

```
30% 3 of 10
50% 5 of 10
60% 6 of 10
100% 10 of 10
```

Мне надо:

```
30% 1 of 4
50% 2 of 4
60% 3 of 4
100% 4 of 4
```

Как?

Answer (score 0):

На основе фрагмента из справки, по внедрению собственного параметра в прогрессбар.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

class TqdmTick(tqdm):
    def __init__(self, ticks, *args, **kwargs):
        self._ticks = ticks
        self._tick = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tick(self, value):
        self._tick += 1
        self.update(value)

    @property
    def format_dict(self):
        d = super().format_dict
        d.update(tick=str(self._tick), ticks=str(self._ticks))
        return d

fmt = '{tick} of {ticks} {percentage:3.0f}%'

iteration = (3, 2, 1, 4)
bar = TqdmTick(ticks=len(iteration), total=sum(iteration), bar_format=fmt)

for i in iteration:
    sleep(i)
    bar.tick(i)
```